# Android - Weird behaviour with AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-softkeyboard

I have an AlertDialog containing a ListView. One Item on the ListView has an EditText.
When cliking the EditText the **keyboard won't show** :

[image]

The code for `EditText` (I don't think that's what causing the issue)

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editableEditText"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:maxLines="1"/>
```

Comment: Please share the code of EditText.

Comment: Pretty simple stuff, see the edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to add this code:

```
dialog.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE|WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM);
```

should be the way. To me worked

EDIT:

this is another way i found:

```
 Dialog = builder.create(); Dialog.show(); 
    Dialog.getWindow().clearFlags( 
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE 
    |WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM); 
 Dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_‌​VISIBLE);
```

Comment: Nop didn't work, the keyboard still won't show on EditText focus

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `setSoftInputMode`

Example code snippet -

```
AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
...

AlertDialog dialog = b.create();
dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
dialog.show();
```

Comment: Didn't work for me, the keyboard still won't show on EditText focus

Answer (score 0):

Try It

```
dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
```